# How can I use "file://" URLs from my Firefox snap version?

Tags: firefox, snap

Local access to files via `file://` seems no more possible outside the sandbox filesystem, the snap version of Firefox is referring to when one uses such URLs. Note that `file://` URLs *are allowed* but they seem to point inside some kind of sandbox. I'm not familiar with the snap architecture, so excuse my jargon, but what I mean is, e.g., `file:///usr/lib/jvm/...` is of course not available in the sandbox system but only on my root file system.

[Solutions circumventing  access security policies](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1264779) wouldn't work because of that construction. In fact, [the Mozilla support website](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1377872) recommends to install the plain FF package. [Further issues](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1972762) filed suggest that this is not optimal for other reasons and that there is no obvious solution. (I, e.g., need that feature because my Java IDE uses `file://` URLs to direct me to the local Java API docs, but there are many other applications that would expect such access to work.)

My question, hence, is, can I use `file://` URLs to access my root file system as usual with the Firefox snap version without the need to switch back to the FF deb version and without the need to circumvent security policies, e.g., in `about:config`?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it has nothing to do with the snap version. The current firefox versions disable the access to local files (both snap and deb) and you have to allow this explicitly for specific websites, e.g with an entry in `/etc/firefox/policies/policies.json`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael, for your answer. You're absolutely right. I was perhaps unclear: even if you adjust the Firefox settings, you need to get access to the outside file system where the whole bunch of other packages' files are located. E.g. JDK documentation in my case or whatever other applications you like. So, the problem is really that the snap sandbox scheme has the expected pros and, apparently, quite a few really nasty cons. :)